# Supertest test flash values with redirection

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, supertest

If I have the following route:

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  req.flash('errors', 'error');
  return res.redirect('/');
});
```

And the following supertest test:

```
describe('POST /', () => {
  it('should return a flash error', (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post('/')
      .expect('Location', '/')
      .expect(302)
      .end((err, res) => {
          console.log(res);
      });
    });
});
```

How can I verify the flash value? I logged the response and I can't find where they are stored. I found online that it might be in the body or text, but they are both empty. Is there another way? If it can help, I'm using this [boilerplate](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter) with most things as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question is still active, but try to use `request.redirect`.
There are some examples in the `express-flash` repository: https://github.com/RGBboy/express-flash/blob/master/test/flash.spec.js